# How to make a dialog alway on top of everything

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

How to make a dialog always on top of everything in Dynamics AX 2012? Following is not working:

```
dialog.formrun().design().alwaysOnTop(true);
```

Should I use `hWnd`? Because I want the form to be on top of any other form but I didn't find any working solution.

Answer (score 3):

You seams interested in a [modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window).

You have several options:

- use the [Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/box.aspx) class, which have methods like `okCancel`
- use a [drop dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg886598.aspx) (AX 2012 forward only)
- use a `formRun.wait(true)` (or even `this.wait((true)`) as [explained here](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Modal_forms)
- use `dialog.parmIsModal(true)` when using a [dialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa877843.aspx)

Comment: Can you post the solution or just try the 3rd option that Jan explained?

Comment: Thanks Jan, but I didn't use Jan's options, because these are not fit our business logic. I have 2 working solutions for this problem now. 1,I write a new class extends 'dialog' class, and override 'wait' method(this is for AX version under 2012). 2, I use dialog.parmIsModal(true) method when I write a dialog, this method only exists in AX 2012. Thanks.